# Why does declaring string give me a syntax error?

Tags: java, variables

I keep getting a syntax error when i try to type `public string account`.

It says that `string` is invalid and I am stumped on how to 
continue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class BankAccount {

    public string accountNum;

    private double balance; 

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow does not explain basic syntax. Go read a book.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `String` instead of `string`, java is case-sensitive language:

```
public String accountNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a class and must use the correct casing.

Additionally, it is generally good practice to make all class fields `private` and include getter and setter methods as required.

Answer (score -2):

The `String` class in java is camel-cased.